# play dist and copy jar to heroku instead of git push

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Play 2.0/2.1 is running fine on Heroku. However, 'git push' takes a while to finish. Can I use 'play dist' and push a jar to Heroku repo instead of pushing  and compiling on Heroku's server? Is there any disadvantages other than source code maintenance?

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ProductionDist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku indicates some benefits when using the `git push` approach in
[Are there benefits to pushing my source code to Heroku?](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-faq#are-there-benefits-to-pushing-my-source-code-to-heroku)

> - Differences between the build environment and the runtime environment are a common source of bad deploys in traditional deployment environments. Doing the app’s build in the same environment that the app will later run greatly reduces this risk.
> - Pushing code rather than builds gives you and your team greater visibility into what code is deployed where. For example, the command `git diff production/master staging/master` will show the exact code differences between staging and production.
> - Git is highly optimized for transmitting only what has changed. This means that most code pushes (after the first one) will take only seconds, instead of many minutes that it may take to transfer a full build artifact.
> - Deploying with revision control makes for smoother collaboration between team members with deploy rights. For example, it provides an overrideable safeguard against accidentally overwriting a more recent deploy with an older one.

But I'm having some problems with this approach for a pretty simple Play! 2.1 application I'm working on.

I have only a few dependencies and my slug size is already over the 200m limit. For now it is not a problem, but I only expect it to grow.

And some days, you are unable to deploy anything because Heroku uses too much time fetching dependencies used to build only (specially *sbt* stuff). A deployment times out after 10 min.

So I’ll probably switch to deploying the compiled artifacts in the near future.

Comment: how did you deploy the compile artifacts?

Comment: I only did the Heroku approach (pushing the source code), but it caused too much trouble.

Comment: To push the binaries you would [play dist](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionDist) your application, extract the archive and add its contents to a new git repository. Then proceed as a regular Heroku push. You might need to specify a [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) if Heroku does something wrong on the automatic building.

Comment: this is great answer. Do you want to put it in separate answer?